# Having a colorbar for a bar plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

Hi I don't know if this is possible, but I have made a bar plot in python where the color is a hex value.  If I have the value that a hex code corresponds to, is it possible to make a colorbar for my bar plot in python? Or is there a way to use a colormap for bar plots in python?

This is my image right now.  The color corresponds to a value, and I want to add a colorbar that has a range of colors with the value it will be. I have done this for scatter plots but I did not use a color map but just hex values for each bar.

[image: example bar chart]

Comment: a colorbar for a bar plot?  i'm confused.  what meaning does color have in the plot?  can you share a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib does support colobars. Here's the API:

http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html

Here's a code sample of a colorbar associated with a plot:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html

EDIT:

Specifically to a bar plot, you could use a [LinearSegmentedColormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=linearsegmentedcolormap#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) instead of a colorbar, as in [here](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/beautiful-plots-with-pandas-and-matplotlib/)

Comment: i have used a colorbar in the past and read the documentation for using it with scatter plots and other types of plots, but i cannot find an example of having a colorbar with a bar plot specifically

Comment: Why would you have a colorbar with a bar plot? Is the color related to the height, or a different variable?

Comment: a different variable.